# custom android listview with refresh and left swipe

Tags: android, android-listview, ontouchlistener

i created a custom listview where i override  onTouchEvent so i can create my own pull to refresh listview. I check if the user is at the top of the listview then if the user swipes down for a threshold length i refresh. I also need to be able to swipe each row in the listview to the left to delete it. I tired using View.OnTouchListener()  and override the ontouch. I attached the View.OnTouchListener()  to each row in the listview. I attached them in the getview() of my baseadapter. My program crashes when i use both listeners. why? how else can I do this?  Basically i need to attach a listener for the whole listview as well as each row in the listview. Is this possible?

This is how i attach the listener to each row in the listview in the getview() method

```
   convertView.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener() {

    float mDownX;
    private int mSwipeSlop = -1;
    float y;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (mSwipeSlop < 0) {
            mSwipeSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).
                    getScaledTouchSlop();
        }
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.d("",    "this was clicked " + data.get(position));
             mDownX = event.getX();

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                float x = event.getX() + v.getTranslationX();
                float deltaX = x - mDownX;
                float deltaXAbs = Math.abs(deltaX);
                v.setTranslationX((x - mDownX));
                v.setAlpha(1 - deltaXAbs / v.getWidth());



            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {


                data.remove(position);
               Log.d("", "ON UP PRESSED");
               notifyDataSetChanged();

                return true;
            }




        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

I created my on OnrefreshListener, i add it to the listview in the mainActivity

```
        l=(CustomList )findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    A= new ListBaseAdapter(names,this);
    l.setAdapter(A);
    l.setRefreshListener(this);
```

Comment: Can you show the code of both listeners and how you attach them?

Comment: @Salauyou ok i have posted them

Comment: They both work individually, but when i combine them my app fails

Comment: It crashes at runtime or right after app launch?

Comment: @Salauyou- it crashes when i try to scroll on the listview

Comment: Your row listener always returns `true` that disallows parent's view to handle this event too. Try to return `false` in all listeners--first, to let touch events propagate from row to listview, second, to let listview handle default scrolling.

Comment: @Salauyou- i return false from my row listener. now the app doesnt crash but the row listener is not running. The RefreshListener is working

Comment: I just experimented and made a conclusion that I was not right... returning false doesn't make the event propagate to parent, just makes default handler execute. Seems you need to make a custom ListView and override its `dispatchTouchEvent()` as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042142/how-to-consume-child-views-touch-event-in-parent-views-touchlistener