# View.OnTouchListener issue when used with fragments

Tags: android

In a single activity I am replacing multiple fragments with a linear layout. Means, now my "container" layout holds the fragments. I tried setting View.onTouchListener on my following frame layout and linear layout But none is working. Why?

The following is my layout xml of MainActivity:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Following way I am setting onTouchListener inside my MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    mainLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    LinearLayout containerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);


    mainLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            MyToast.showToast("inner main");
            return true;
        }
    });

    containerLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            MyToast.showToast("inner main");
            return true;
        }
    });


    FragmentTransaction tran = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        tran.replace(R.id.container, new RegistrationFragment(), Keys.TAG_REGISTRATION_FRAGMENT);
    tran.commit();
}
```

Comment: can you include your onCreate or onResume where you are adding the fragments?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042142/how-to-consume-child-views-touch-event-in-parent-views-touchlistener

Comment: It is called every time when there is a relevant MotionEvent. Go and try it.